# onPartialResult is always one value, even after I change the keyword?

Tags: java, android, string, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

**`hypothesis.getHypstr()` is always one value, even after I change the keyword!**

I am using `pocketsphinx` to do speech recognition, and I let the user change what to listen for. This value is stored in my shared preferences. My problem is that `hypothesis.getHypstr()` is only called when the previous keyword is spoken.

**For example:**

If it is set to default keyword (oranges and rainbows), then the recognition works fine. But, if the user changes it to "hello computer" then the `onPartialResult` method still only gets called when the user says hello, **and `hypothesis.getHypstr()` is still oranges and rainbows.**

**onCreate:**

```
try {
            Assets assets = new Assets(MyService.this);
            File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
            setupRecognizer(assetDir);

            Log.v(TAG, "SET UP DIRECTORIES STARTING LISTENING!");
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening("usersKeyword");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
        }
```

**setupRecognizer()**

```
public void setupRecognizer(File sphinxDir) {

    try {
        mSpeechRecognizer = defaultSetup()
                .setAcousticModel(new File(sphinxDir, "en-us-ptm"))
                .setDictionary(new File(sphinxDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))
                .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)
                .setKeywordThreshold(1e-40f)
                .getRecognizer();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mSpeechRecognizer.addListener(this);
    mSpeechRecognizer.addKeyphraseSearch("usersKeyword", keyword.getString("keyword", "oranges and rainbows"));

}
```

**onPartialResult:**

```
@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {

    if (hypothesis == null) { //no one spoke 
        return;
    }
    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
    Log.v(TAG, "TEXT: " + text + "hypothesis.getHypstr: " + hypothesis.getHypstr());

    if (text.equals(keyword.getString("keyword", "oranges and rainbows"))) { //Only happens when text is oranges and rainbows, even after changing preference value!!!

        Log.v(TAG, "Heard user keyword!");

        mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
        mSpeechRecognizer.startListening("usersKeyword");

    }

}
```

Why is `hypothesis.getHypstr()` always only one value, even after I change the value of the `addKeyphraseSearch`?

Thanks,

Ruchir

**EDIT:
I actually stop and start the service every time the user changes their input, and so `onCreate()` is called every time the user changes their data.**

FULL CODE:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/47efc9c1ca08d808e0be

Comment: You need to show the full code, not just parts of it.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev The problem is that `hypothesis.getHypstr();` is always `oranges and rainbows`, even after I change the users keyword.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Maybe I need to delete all the asset files before making them? Is there something like an `assets.deleteSync` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to destroy the service, you create it once with `onCreate`.

You can set the command in `onStartCommand`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     recognizer.cancel();
     recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch("usersKeywords", intent.getStringExtra("keyword"););
     recognizer.startListening("usersKeywords");
}
```

From the other class which is a user of the service you start service with intent:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService);
 i.putExtra("keyword", "hello");
 startService(i);
```

For more details read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `mSpeechRecognizer.addKeyphraseSearch()` every time you want to change the key phrase.

Comment: But I have `mSpeechRecognizer.addKeyphraseSearch("usersKeyword", keyword.getString("keyword", "oranges and rainbows"));` in my `setupRecognizer` method. Shouldn't that work? Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Right, but you only call `setupRecognizer()` once.

Comment: I actually stop and start the service every time the user changes their input, and so `onCreate()` is called every time the user changes their data. I have edited the question. Please let me know what I should do now. Thanks :)

Comment: It's hard to say, probably there's the logic flow error. I can help if you post the full source to reproduce.

Comment: Maybe I need to delete all the asset files before making them? Is there something like a `assets.deleteSync` method?

Comment: No, there's no such method. Why would you need that? The code that you wrote should work as expected, so I suspect the error is in the logic.